# jquery thumbnail scroller, autoscroll after hover

Tags: jquery, scroller

Im not really a jQuery buff. So i come here looking for some help.

Here is the idea. i am using the thumbnail scroller script for a scroller.
here's a link to my website:
http://022f5a3.netsolhost.com/usnile/

i have 3 thumbnail scrollers rolling and everytime after mouse hovers the scroller wont start autoscrolling again.
i want to know how to fix this, and make it autoscroll again afte the mouse hovers out of the frame.
here's the source
http://jsbin.com/URijEbe/1/edit

Thanks!!

Comment: try autoscroll:1 instead of 0? really dont know, because i didnt look into it enough to give precise answer.
Well, and you get some 404 errors trying to load some of your JS. you get this error as well: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'". Could lead to this behaviour, too.

Comment: i tried it @razhial the autoscroll just stops after any hover interaction.
but please check my website as everything loads correctly as long as i dont hover over the scroller...

Comment: my chrome debugger doesnt confirm this. you get three 404 errors trying to load some javascript and because of that you get another JS error. All of this with loading of page. so to be absolutely sure this isn't part of your problem you should fix this first.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i corrected the fancybox problem i deleted the coding for it as it wasnt in use in the website. but the scrolling problem persists... :/ @razhial